# how to get eureka custom cell's indexpath.row , button tag

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I made a custom cell added a button, labels inside.

to delete the cell, when clicking the button, it will `pass array[Index]`, using like `button.tag = indexPath.row`, then request to the server.

by the way, those functions dont work below:

```
.onCellSelection{ cell, row in ...} 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

---

> also inside `.cellUpdate`, `row.indexPath`? is `nil`. hopefully could
>   get the indexPath with the button.

---

> custom cell

```
public class SnsReplyCell: Cell<Tmp_ReplyList>, CellType {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var replyUser: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var replyBody: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var delBtn: UIButton!

public override func setup() {
    height = { return 75 }
    row.title = nil
    row.value = nil
    super.setup()
    selectionStyle = .none

    profileImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    profileImg.clipsToBounds = true
    guard let tmp = row.value else { return } /
    replyUser.text = tmp.userid
    replyBody.text = tmp.body



}

public override func update() {
    super.update()
    guard let tmp = row.value else { return } 
    replyUser.text = tmp.userInfo.name
    replyBody.text = tmp.body
    profileImg.image = loadImageFromUrl(img_Url: tmp.userInfo.imageUrl).circle


}
```

}

```
public final class SnsReplyRow : Row<SnsReplyCell>, RowType {

required public init(tag: String?) {
    super.init(tag: tag)
    cellProvider = CellProvider<SnsReplyCell>(nibName: "SnsReplyCell")
}
```

}

> config section,

```
var rows : [BaseRow] = []
var section1 = Section()


func replyFormConfig() -> Section{

    section1.header?.height = { 1 }
    self.tableView?.separatorStyle = .none

    for option in snsReplies {
        section1.append(SnsReplyRow(){

            $0.value = Tmp_ReplyList(tripid: option.tripid, pinid: option.pinid, userid: option.userid, body: option.body, date: option.date, _id: option._id, userInfo: option.userInfo!)


            $0.validationOptions = .validatesOnChange
            }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
                row.section?.form?.validate()

                cell.delBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.delAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

            }).cellUpdate { cell, row in


                cell.replyUser.text = option.userInfo?.name
                cell.replyBody.text = option.body
                cell.profileImg.image = loadImageFromUrl(img_Url: (option.userInfo?.imageUrl)!).circle

                // indexPath = nil below;
                cell.delBtn.tag = row.indexPath.row  

                cell.delBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.delAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

                if !row.isValid {
                    cell.replyUser.text = "is not valid"
                    cell.replyBody.text = option.body

                }
            }
            .onCellSelection { cell, row in
                row.section?.form?.validate()

                // indexPath = nil below too;
                cell.delBtn.tag = row.indexPath.row  
            }
        )//append


    }

    return section1

}
```

> delete, when clicking the de button.

```
 func delAction(_ sender: UIButton){

   // sender.tag is cell.delBtn.tag below;
    let parameters = ["userid": snsReplies[sender.tag].userid, "replyid": snsReplies[sender.tag]._id]



    Alamofire.request(pom_url + "/sns/reply/delete", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response.result)

        switch response.result {
        case.success(let data):


            self.section1.remove(at: self.delBtnTag)

        case.failure:
            print("[sns/reply/delete] err")

            }
        }
    }




       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.delBtn.tag = indexPath.row   //not Working
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
for (index,option) in snsReplies.enumerated() {
 }
```

you can use index as indexPath.row, and use it like here

```
 func replyFormConfig() -> Section{

        section1.header?.height = { 1 }
        self.tableView?.separatorStyle = .none

        for (index,option) in snsReplies.enumerated() {
            section1.append(SnsReplyRow(){

                $0.value = Tmp_ReplyList(tripid: option.tripid, pinid: option.pinid, userid: option.userid, body: option.body, date: option.date, _id: option._id, userInfo: option.userInfo!)


                $0.validationOptions = .validatesOnChange
                }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
                    row.section?.form?.validate()

                    cell.delBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.delAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

                }).cellUpdate { cell, row in


                    cell.replyUser.text = option.userInfo?.name
                    cell.replyBody.text = option.body
                    cell.profileImg.image = loadImageFromUrl(img_Url: (option.userInfo?.imageUrl)!).circle

                    // indexPath = nil below;
                    cell.delBtn.tag = index

                    cell.delBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.delAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

                    if !row.isValid {
                        cell.replyUser.text = "is not valid"
                        cell.replyBody.text = option.body

                    }
                }
                .onCellSelection { cell, row in
                    row.section?.form?.validate()

                    // indexPath = nil below too;
                    cell.delBtn.tag = index
                }
            )//append


        }

        return section1

    }
```

I hope this helps you, if you have any problem with this please let me know, I will help you

Comment: Sorry for getting you feedback lately. so great!!! Thank you very much!!